# How can I download all the data folders available in a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

In general, if a website displays a series of links to data containing folders (i.e. spreadsheets with economic data), how can I write a program that identifies all the links and downloads the data?

In particular, I am trying to download all folders from 2012 to 2018 in this website https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/viirs/download_dnb_composites.html

I tried the approach suggested below, yet it seems the links to the data are not downloaded.

```
my_target='https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/viirs/download_dnb_composites.html'


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get(my_target)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

links=[]
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Among all URL appended to links, none directs to the data.

Finally, even once I have the right links, how can they be used to actually download the files?

Many thanks! ;)

Comment: So, you have the link to all the files but you don't know how to download them?

Comment: Unfortunately I need both :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical web scraping task.

- Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to download the page
- then parse the content and extract the URLs using[beutifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- you can now download the files using their extracted URLs and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

Comment: Actually it is not that simple. The links are not directly available after a simple URL extraction. Even in the parsed html, they are not here. It is as if the drop down menu of the website was making some external request

Comment: Then you should use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to extract the URLs or to feed the page source, after handling all the dynamic stuff, back to beautifulsoup.

Comment: Thanks a lot @m9mhmdy for redirecting to selenium! However, being quite new to webscraping I wouldn´know where to start. It would be very helpful to get further clarification!

Comment: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72